# Powershell: How To Parse Piped CSV Select-String Line Value into Values in Another Array

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell, hashtable

I am updating 288K SPO Doc Library Items with metadata from a CSV file.
I am having trouble parsing the output of a Select-String object into values in my uploading Metadata array as shown here:

```
# Get Row from CSV File
$csv | Select-String -SimpleMatch $item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef | % {

# Collect the Metadata from CSV File
$Metadata = @{}
$Metadata.add(  "TcID",          $_.TcItemID)
$Metadata.add(  "LegacyID",      $_.LegacyID)
$Metadata.add(  "_Prefix",       $_.Prefix)
$Metadata.add(  "_Series",       $_.Series.PadLeft(3,'0'))
$Metadata.add(  "_Base",         $_.Base.PadLeft(3,'0'))
```

[Array Parse Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OVey.jpg)

Edit 6/3: This is the value from the Select-String Line Property:

```
@{Filename=ad3402230000.pdf; TcItemID=AD-340-223-00; SedaID=ad3402230000.pdf; Name=ASSEMBLY; Description=PEP2
H/L STR MAG VOLT DIV BOX; ItemType=Design; Revision=00; Date Created=1998/03/11; Last Modified Date=1998/03/11;
Release Status=Released; Date Released=1998/03/11;
GrpDiscipline=Electrical; ExtSource=; LegacyID=; Prefix=AD;
Series=340; Base=223; Suffix=00; CatCode=PEP3200; ccProgram=PEP-Positron Electron Project;
ccCatMajor=32-Accelerator Power Systems; ccCatMinor=00-Misc; ProjectOrigin=PEP 2; Approvers=S LOWE; Checkers=SLOWE; CreatedBy=W GORECKI;
Designers=W GORECKI; DocType=Drawing; DocSubType=AD-Assembly Drawing;
ECDate=; ECID=; ECRequestor=; ECStatus=; Engineers=D MACNAIR; Image=Y; ParentImage=; LegacyStatus=Released; IPGroup=; See=; Spires=PEP2 H/L STR MAG VOLT DIV BOX; Title1=PEP II HER/LER STRING MAGNET; Title2=VOLTAGE DIVIDER BOX;
Title3=ASSEMBLY; Title4=}
```

This looks like a hash table, but is actually a string...
How do I convert this string back into a hash table, then parse the name=value pairs for inclusion in my metadata hash table?

Thx

EDIT 6/6: Days of Net scouring led me to a convoluted solution that does what I need it to do, albeit ridiculously slowly... it looks like this:

```
# Get Row from CSV File containing filename
$row = $csv | Select-String -SimpleMatch $item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -List -Quiet | select -ExpandProperty Line
$a = @($row.Trim('{','@').Replace("; ",";").Replace('}','').Split(';')) | ConvertFrom-StringData
# Collect the Metadata from CSV File
$Metadata = @{}
$Metadata.add(  "TcID",          $a.TcItemID)
$Metadata.add(  "LegacyID",      $a.LegacyID)
$Metadata.add(  "_Prefix",       $a.Prefix)
$Metadata.add(  "_Series",       $a.Series.PadLeft(3,'0'))
$Metadata.add(  "_Base",         $a.Base.PadLeft(3,'0'))
$Metadata.add(  "_Suffix",       $a.Suffix.PadLeft(2,'0'))
```

There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you include an example line from you csv file?

Comment: Thx @Jason, I added a line from the CSV file above. The image link above shows what is returned from the Select-String call, and all of the listed attributes are in there. I just can't find the syntax to access the array values for assignment to the Metadata array.